# Refresh a Servlet by another Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, iframe, refresh

I have to create a little webshop for a school-project, but entered in to a problem during the process by updating/refreshing the `Servlets`.

Description:
I created an `index.html` file which includes two servlets via `iframes`, the left side for `Navigation-Servlet` and on the right the `Controller-Servlet` does something to show a welcome page (or shows off the categories etc.) - works all fine.

But now I have to implement a login with an small administration.
By clicking in the navigation on `Administration`, it leads to another `Servlet` called `Administration-Servlet`, in the right iframe (actually not over the `Controller-Servlet`).

There comes up a login mask, where the user put in his username and password. If the login was correct, it leads then to the administration content (not finished by now).

The upcoming problem is now that I somehow have to update/refresh the `Navigation iframe` too, when the login was successful because there must be the `Logout-Button` and some entries have to be hidden.

By which "technique" or pattern I can solve this problem? Maybe a little code example would be helpful. :)

Best greets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Iframes to put together the different parts of your site, use dynamic include in your servlets. This will allow you to build the response page server side and therefore dynamically change what is included in a page. When you log in you send the authentication request to the servlet which will then dynamically construct the new response from multiple JSP files.

```
<jsp:include page="..." />
```

Another solution is to use a scripting language like Apache Velocity Template scripts to build your responses dynamically. Allowing you to include or exclude information depending on parameters or session context.